# CloudSQL close idle connections

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I want to create an instance in cloudSQL. I am a google app engine with PHP. I would like to know about idle connections, and how much I will be charged. It says that idle connections will be active for around 12 hours. I dont want that to happen. Right now , my script looks like this:

```
<?php
include 'database.php'; //connects to the database
    while($time<60)
    {

    if(any new messages) {
    die (new messages) 
    }



    sleep(1);
    $time++;

    }

die(no new messages);
```

There is no place where I am running `mysqli_close` here. so even if this script stops executing, am I still going to be charged money ? if so, what should I do to shut down the cloudsql instance when not in use ?

Answer (score 1):

We drop the connections when the script finishes executing - you do not need to explicitly call mysqli_close() for this to happen.